# Reordering Lists like playlists in the media player

Tags: android, list, playlist

I have a list of items that are displayed using a ListView from a SQLCursor.  The SQL table includes(as well as other things) a _id field and an order field.  I use the order field to sort the list before it gets to the ListView.

What I need is a widget like the MediaPlayer has in its playlist view.  It allows you to click the icon and drag the item in the playlist around and put it into a new order.  With that ability I can then retrieve the new order and update the SQL table with the new order.  However, I am not having any luck finding any clues to help me add that functionality into my program.

The question is whether I can use existing functions to help me, or do I need to manually program motion events and such until I get nearly the same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I am not having any luck
>   finding any clues to help me add that
>   functionality into my program.

If you want the functionality from the Music application (which, by the way, is not named "MediaPlayer"), [go look at its source code](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=summary). Here is a StackOverflow [question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940117/android-drag-and-drop-list-rearrange) that point you to the specific class (`TouchInterceptor`) that enables the drag-and-drop.

> The question is whether I can use
>   existing functions to help me, or do I
>   need to manually program motion events
>   and such until I get nearly the same
>   functionality.

If you are looking for a widget with built-in drag-and-drop, there is none in the SDK.

Comment: well alrighty.  That answers all my questions!  annoying that I couldn't find that question you referred to in stack overflow myself.  Hopefully I can figure out how to use that TouchInterceptor properly and really get my program rolling!  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't played with `TouchInterceptor`, so I do not know how reusable it is. I get the impression -- such as from that other SO question -- that others are successfully using it. Cleaning it up into a separate reusable widget is on my list of 18,000 things to do...