# reordering of listview items by drag and drop using android

Tags: android

How to drag and drop items in Listview for reordering in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android List View Drag and Drop sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort)

Answer (score 15):

Here is our drag & drop list. It is a direct replacement for ListView and it's very easy to use. There are examples of how to use it on the github page.

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList

Comment: There is cursor parameter passed inside the adaptor. Can u give any sample code that uses this library?

Answer (score 7):

A good example on the topic can be found here: https://github.com/mtparet/Drag-And-Drop-Android

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed elsewhere. Try:

[Reordering Lists like playlists in the media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564266/reordering-lists-like-playlists-in-the-media-player)

or

[Android - drag and drop - list rearrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940117/android-drag-and-drop-list-rearrange)

Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy way to do it. You'll have to handle touch events at a fairly low level.

Answer (score 3):

Check this.. exactly what you needed. 
[Drag and Drop](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html)

Comment: This drag and drop example does not work completely. If you ListView has more tiems than fit on the screen, it does not scroll as you try to drag. Use this one instead:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist