# adding items to expandable list view by drag and drop android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

how to add items to the expandable list by drag and drop ?e.g If you drag and drop some text it should be added in expandable list.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to draw a custom component see this page for more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html.

You would need to override the draw method and draw your own list view as well as where ever your dragging your items from. This is a complicated task and may seem daunting but I haven't really seen anyone do a drag and drop on android before. You may be the first!

If you need to simply reorder your listview then you should check out this thread:

[reordering of listview items by drag and drop using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141144/reordering-of-listview-items-by-drag-and-drop-using-android)