# Changing list order after dragging in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using Drag n Drop in my list view.Its working very fine but the problem is how i change the order of elements after dragging too.Suppose i have a list view with elements 1 at 0 position, 2 at 1 position 3 at 2 position and so on. So when i click on the item at position 2 it is giving me item at position 1 and it is right too but after dragging suppose i replace 2 by 1.it should give me data that is associated with 1 but it is again giving me data of 2.so how it is possible.any help would be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
public class DragNDropListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.dragndroplistview);
Button mbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
mbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i=new Intent(DragNDropListActivity.this,FormulaActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }
});
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(mListContent.length);
for (int i=0; i < mListContent.length; i++) {
    content.add(mListContent[i]);
}

  setListAdapter(new DragNDropAdapter(this, new int[]{R.layout.dragitem}, new int[] 
 {R.id.TextView01}, content));//new DragNDropAdapter(this,content)
  ListView listView = getListView();

  if (listView instanceof DragNDropListView) {
    ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDropListener(mDropListener);
    ((DragNDropListView) listView).setRemoveListener(mRemoveListener);
    ((DragNDropListView) listView).setDragListener(mDragListener);
   }
}

 private DropListener mDropListener = 
 new DropListener() {
 public void onDrop(int from, int to) {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
        ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onDrop(from, to);
        getListView().invalidateViews();
    }
}
};

 private RemoveListener mRemoveListener =
new RemoveListener() {
public void onRemove(int which) {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof DragNDropAdapter) {
        ((DragNDropAdapter)adapter).onRemove(which);
        getListView().invalidateViews();
    }
}
};

 private DragListener mDragListener =
 new DragListener() {

int backgroundColor = 0xe0103000;

    public void onDrag(int x, int y, ListView listView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onStartDrag(View itemView) {
        itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onStopDrag(View itemView) {
        itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

  };

      private static String[] mListContent={"1","2","3"};
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185545/saving-the-contents-of-the-listview-after-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

You need to change (override) the onDrop() method of DragNDropAdapter in order to synchronize these changes.