# Android dynamic rearranging layout

Tags: android, dynamic, android-layout, user-interface

I need to create a UI that allows the user to rearrange its elements and store the configuration of that arrangement somewhere. And when the user opens the application the UI would load as the user arranged it.

Just like you would rearrange the icons and widgets on the homescreen. Is there a tutorial for that? What approach would you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is farly near rearranging items on a ListView. You should check this question:

[reordering of listview items by drag and drop using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141144/reordering-of-listview-items-by-drag-and-drop-using-android)