# How to make an Advanced user interface in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

i wonder how you can make an advanced Android User interface where you can add for example a drag drop and more graphics options?  is that by using OpenGl ?!

this is example of UI in iPhone Apps.

[example 1](http://flyosity.com/images/_blogentries/designpatterns/beats.png)

[example 2](http://flyosity.com/images/_blogentries/designpatterns/postage.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples just seem to be composed of a lot of nice images. Your first example looks pretty static and could probably be made from buttons with custom images and setting lots of backgrounds on your layout items. The second looks like you would need to make a custom `Gallery` and do a little more manipulation and composition of images so it might be worth your time to go a little lower level for performance.

Basically, you're looking at using a lot of images. You can make them work with existing widgets and components and get the functionality more easily, or you can use OpenGL ect. To get some more flexibility and performance at the cost of having to code all the functionality in yourself.

If you're looking at drag and drop [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940117/android-drag-and-drop-list-rearrange) post points to the source for a `ListView` with some rudimentary drag and drop functionality.