# Is it possible to re-arrange items in a list view?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

On the iPhone a user is able to re-arrange the actual rows in a list. Is this possible on Android? If so, any examples would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [reusable `TouchListView`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist) that addresses this issue, at least in part.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by drag-n-drop?

[Android - drag and drop - list rearrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940117/android-drag-and-drop-list-rearrange)