# Drag and drop in API level 8

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an app that contains a `ListView` populated with deals. I want to long press an item and drag and drop it onto the bottom side as it's bought.

My API level is 8 so `ClipData` cannot be used.

What can I do?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1941210/556586

Comment: Thanks! It was useful for me! I'll try to use it